# How to add linked list node automaticly?

Tags: java, linked-list

Firstly i dont have good english.I have a question.
Question: 10 beds in a hospital bed empty and full follow-up is intended to be controlled by a linked list. When a patient to the hospital or when a patient is discharged automatically perform assignments in a Java.

How can i add nodes automaticly?
I want like this:
First patient added 1. bed.
Second patient added 2.bed.
Third patient added 3.bed.
.
.
.
Example:If i delete second patient it will going to be null and the newly added patient will be second patient autamaticly.I must do it with Linked-List.Sorry for my bad english again.

```
 public class Yatak {
    static int no;


    Yatak ilkYatak = null;
    Yatak sonYatak = null;
    Yatak sonraki;

    //Hasta tut;





    public Yatak() {

        this.sonraki = null;
    }

public void hastaEkle() {

        Yatak yeniEklenen = new Yatak();

        // Eğer hiç bir hasta kayıtlı değilse ilk eklediğimiz hastayı listenin
        // başına ve sonuna atıyoruz.
        if (ilkYatak == null) {
            ilkYatak = yeniEklenen;
            sonYatak = yeniEklenen;
        }

         /* Eğer daha önceden kayıtlı bir hasta varsa yeni ekleyeceğimiz hasta
         * sonYatak oluyor. Yani listenin en son elemanı oluyor.
         */
        else {
            sonYatak.sonraki = yeniEklenen;
            sonYatak = yeniEklenen;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure that u have to use linked list? Or these are task conditions?
In general, if you have to put element on defined by index place it should be better to use arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to implement Linked list by yourself. Else standard java.util.LinkedList will do this for you. example..

```
    LinkedList<String> bed = new LinkedList<String>();
    bed.add("Patient 1");
    bed.add("Patient 2");
    bed.add("Patient 3");
    bed.add("Patient 4");

    System.out.println(bed);

    // Removing patient 3
    bed.remove(2);

    System.out.println(bed);
```